# Why does Docker reuse the image for only some of builds from the same Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Multiple users ran 'docker build' on the same VM from the same app binaries and Dockerfile over a duration of 1 hour, using the same image name and different tags.

On viewing the images, I only see 2 of the image:tags with the same image ID. All other images have unique image IDs.

What could have caused this behavior?

Comment: docker build --no-cache or not?

Comment: no-cache was not used for any of the builds.